# Cascading parameters in SSRS Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have 4 **parameters in ssrs report**, one is **country**, one is **state**, one is **city**, and one is **persons**,
I need to do that, when i select country, desired state automatically get selected, same is when i select state desired city gets selected and when i select city i need that in the ***4th drop down of persons all the person residing in the choosen city automatically comes***, i do not want to choose them,
please anyone?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to create a dataset for each of your parameters that references the parent parameter.

I've assumed your tables have an ID field and a Name/Description field

So, starting at the lowest level your `persons` dataset (call it say `dsPersons`) would look something like

```
SELECT PersonID, PersonName FROM Persons WHERE CityID IN(@CityID)
```

Edit your persons parameter and set the available values to be from a query and choose your dataset (`dsPerons`) that we created above. Set the `value` to be the ID field (if you have one) and the `label` to be the name/description field that you want visible to the user. In the case  of persons you can also set the default values to be the same dataset, this will automatically select all entries.

Doing the above will automatically create the @CityID parameter so we just repeat the steps above, createa new dataset `dsCity` with a query like

```
SELECT CityID, CityName FROM Cities WHERE CountryID IN(@StateID)
```

Set the available values to come from the `dsCity` dataset but you don't have to set the default here (unless you want all cities selected automatically)

Repeat this process for each parameter...

**Note:** Make sure each parameter is set to multi-value where applicable. Also, I used ' Field IN (@param)`rather than`Field = @param` in case you wanted to select more than 1 city, state or country

For further reading...

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498(v=sql.105).aspx